# urls en asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

¿Se puede dejar las urls de mi aplicación web de la siguiente forma?. Ejemplo:

Url normal -> `localhost/MiControlador/MiAccion`

Url convertida -> `localhost/mi-controller/mi-accion` o `localhost/MiController/mi-accion`

**MAS INFORMACIÓN**

Mi RouteConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{Size}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Signin", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional, Size = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Mi Controller:

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    // GET: User
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("User/l-ogin")]
    public ActionResult Login() => View();
}
```

Comment: [`[Route]`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)

Comment: Pero como se ocupa? por que a a la `class` de mi `controller` le asigne ´[RoutePrefix("users")]´ siendo que mi controlador se llama ´MiController : Controller´ pero cuando ejecuto el view en la url sigue apareciendo este ultimo y no el `users`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posibilidad, sería utilizar el Data Anotation `[Route]` para esto, primero, hay que activar `MapMvcAttributeRoutes()` en la clase `RouteConfig.cs`

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        //Rutas por defecto
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );   
    }
}
```

Luego, bastaría con usar `[Route]` en el método donde quieras customizar su ruta

**Sin parámetros**

```
[Route("~/ControladorA/el-ejemplo")]
     public ViewResult metodoEjemplo()
     {
         return View();
         //En este ejemplo la ruta sería http://localhost/ControladorA/el-ejemplo
     }
```

**Con Parámetros**

```
[Route("~/Pelicula/{idpelicula}")]
     public ViewResult metodoEjemplo(int idpelicula)
     {             
         return View();
         //En este ejemplo la ruta sería, por ejemplo  http://localhost/Pelicula/3
         //donde 3 representa el id de una película
     }
```

Para obtener más información del tema podes ver directamente la **[Documentación de Microsoft](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)**, ya que veras distintas opciones para llegar al mismo resultado, y quizás encuentres una que te sea más cómoda

Saludos

Comment: No me funciona... estoy haciendo lo siguiente tengo un controlador por ejemplo `public class UserController : Controller` y una acción que se llama `public ActionResult Login()` a mi acción le agregue el atributo `[Route("~/User/el-ejemplo")]` que contiene el nombre del controlador junto con el nombre de la acción que quiero que aparezca como url  pero me da un error que dice: No se encuentra el recurso. La urls que me entrega es la misma de antes, no la que realmente quiero. Ya configure el route en el archivo .cs

Comment: Podrías editar la pregunta y agregar código de tu `RouteConfig.cs`?, según lo que me decís deberías poder ingresar con `localhost/User/el-ejemplo`

Comment: Pregunta editada, agregue mas antecedentes.

Comment: @vcasas Proba ubicar `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` arriba de `routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");`
 en lugar de abajo

Comment: Tampoco :/  me dice "Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'." "No se encuentra el recurso." y la url que muestra sigue siendo el nombre del controlador y de la accion

Comment: Te podrías fijar que ruta renderiza la función @Url.Action() dentro de una vista?

Comment: renderiza `/User/Login` pero tuve que sacar el `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` para que no me diera el error en la vista

Comment: ¿Cuál era el error que te daba?

Comment: > Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'. No se encuentra el recurso.

Comment: Eso en la ruta que te generaba? me refiero a la excepción por la que tuviste que sacar `routes.MapMvcAttributesRoutes();`

Comment: Ese es el error... me lo entrega la vista al iniciar el controlador. Ademas me dice esto: HTTP 404. El recurso que está buscando (o una de sus dependencias) se puede haber quitado, haber cambiado de nombre o no estar disponible temporalmente. Revise la dirección URL siguiente y asegúrese de que está escrita correctamente.

Comment: Podrías probar de poner el RouteConfig.cs tal cual está el mio? Aver si logramos depurar el error

Comment: Ahora funciono, pero resulta que escribir la url para llegar hasta ahí, pensé que al ejecutar la vista que contiene a esa acción me ejecutaría la url nueva que le había asignado, pero no lo hace. Solo funciona si escribo esa nueva url en el navegador. Funciona así? o de igual forma hay algo mal?

Comment: Hay algo mal `Url.Action()` debería darte la nueva ruta, estando todo de esta manera, te sigue dando la ruta `/User/Login` ?

Comment: `Url.Action()` ahora me da la ruta nueva `/users/iniciar-sesion` pero lo que tengo dudas ahora es si ejecuto esa vista desde el VS no me abre directamente hacia esa url si no que me abre con el nombre original del `controller` y de la `action` eso esta bien?

Comment: La verdad con eso me mataste, a mi también me pasa (lo note por primera vez ahora que me dijiste), de todos modos, no tendría porque generar conflictos, mientras la ruta que vos queres te dirija hacia donde queres y las funciones de renderizado retornen la ruta que vos pretendes, todo sería correcto

Comment: Genial ! muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda =)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el atributo [`Route`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/) donde especificas un formato de tu url.

Por ejemplo:

```
public classs HomeController : Controller{
    public ActionResult Index() {
      return View();
    }
}
```

Normalmente para invocar index seria `/home/index`. Agregando el atributo `Route` puedes cambiar la url de ese controlador. Por ejemplo digamos que quieres que sea `/h-ome/index`:

```
public classs HomeController : Controller{

   [Route("h-ome/index/")]
   public ActionResult Index() {
        return View();
   }
}
```

Con route puedes simular subdirectorios tambien:

```
[Route("home/user/start")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
  //...
}
```

Donde la url seria `/home/user/start` y por lo tanto Index se ejecutaria.

Dale una mirada a la [documentacion](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/) para que se empapes bien del tema.

---

Bono: Si tu action requiere parametros, con Route puedes hacer la url mas amigable, como por ejemplo, para ver la información del usuario, normalmente seria `/user/info?username=einer`. Esto se puede cambiar a `/user/einer/info`:

```
[Route("user/{username}/info")]
public ActionResult UserInfo(string username) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Pero como se ocupa? por que a a la `class` de mi `controller` le asigne `[RoutePrefix("users")]` siendo que mi controlador se llama `MiController : Controller` pero cuando ejecuto el view en la url sigue apareciendo este ultimo y no el `users`

Comment: `RoutePrefixAttribute` no es igual a `RouteAttribute`. `RoutePrefix se utiliza para solo para el controlador mientras que Route es tanto para el controlador com para el action.

Comment: Lo acabo de probar con el `Route` y nada tampoco... lo estaré haciendo mal? o hay que habilitar algo..?

Comment: En la carpeta AppStart hay una clase llamada `RouteConfig`, en el metodo `RegisterRoutes` agreaga `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` para activar el Route

Comment: No me funciona... estoy haciendo lo siguiente tengo un controlador por ejemplo `public class UserController : Controller` y una acción que se llama `public ActionResult Login()` a mi acción le agregue el atributo `[Route("~/User/el-ejemplo")]` que contiene el nombre del controlador junto con el nombre de la acción que quiero que aparezca como url  pero me da un error que dice: No se encuentra el recurso. La urls que me entrega es la misma de antes, no la que realmente quiero. Ya configure el route en el archivo .cs

Comment: Cambia `[Route("~/User/el-ejemplo")]` por `Route("User/el-ejemplo")]`

Comment: Actualice mi pregunta para que puedas ver lo que tengo, por que aun así sigue sin funcionar..